# Move Semantics with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, move-semantics

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 and am having trouble trying to understand why std::vector is trying to use the copy constructor of unique_ptr.  I have looked at similar issues and most are related to not having an explicit move constructor and/or operator.

If I change the member variable to a string, I can verify that the move constructor is called; however, trying to use the unique_ptr results in the compilation error:

`error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'`.

I'm hoping someone can point me to what I am missing, thanks!

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class MyObject
{
public:
    MyObject() : ptr(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int))
    {
    }

    MyObject(MyObject&& other) : ptr(std::move(other.ptr))
    {
    }

    MyObject& operator=(MyObject&& other)
    {
        ptr = std::move(other.ptr);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<MyObject> s;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        MyObject o;
        s.push_back(o);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to construct your objects directly in the vector, you can also just `emplace` them: `for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) s.emplace_back();` That should work with VC11 too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `push_back()` function takes its argument by value. Therefore, an attempt is made to either copy-construct the argument of `push_back()` (if you are passing an lvalue), or to move-construct it (if you are passing an rvalue).

In this case, `o` is an lvalue - because **named objects are lvalues** - and rvalue references cannot bind to lvalues. Therefore, the compiler cannot invoke your move constructor.

In order to have your object *moved*, you have to write:

```
s.push_back(std::move(o));
//          ^^^^^^^^^
```

What surprises me in this case is that it seems VC11 generated a copy-constructor for `MyObject` implicitly without defining it as *deleted* (judging from the error you posted). This should not be the case, since your class declares a move constructor. Per Paragraph 12.8/7 of the C++11 Standard, in fact:

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared implicitly. **If the class
>   definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor
>   is defined as deleted**; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4)

I must conclude that while the error you are getting is correct - because you are not passing an rvalue to `push_back()` - VC11 is not fully compliant here.

Comment: Great! I was not aware of this.  I am still a little confused as to why the move constructor gets called just by changing the unique_ptr to a string though.  If VC11 is generating an implicit copy constructor, I would expect that to be used since I did not use std::move.

Comment: @zYzil: The correct behavior would be not to invoke the copy constructor nor the move constructor of `std::string` (see [this live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kW04t$377)), since `MyObject` is non-copyable and you are not moving from it. If your code looks *exactly* like my example (including the missing `std::move()`), then VC11 has a bug.

Comment: I definitely think there is a bug in VC11.  [This example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1edTJY$3) does not compile on GCC 4.8.0; however, on VC11 it compiles and outputs "Move ctor" due to the move constructor being called.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @zYzil: Sounds like a bug, indeed. Good luck with your project!

Comment: VC11 doesn't yet implement the rules about automatic creation of move constructors and inhibition of automatic creation of copy constructors. I think STL refers to these parts as rvalue reference 3.0, and VC11 only implements 2.1.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: OK, that explains. Thank you for the information

Answer (score 4):

`MyObject o;` defines `o` to be an object. Which means it's a l-value. Doing `s.push_back(o);` then invokes the l-value overload of `push_back()` (it has no other choice), which tries to create a copy.

Since your class is noncopyable, you have to *move* the object into the vector:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    MyObject o;
    s.push_back(std::move(o));
}
```