# Assign temporary struct pointer as struct member

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, member

Let's say i have the following structs:

```
struct Foo
{
  int val;
};
struct Test
{
  Foo *bar;
};
```

and I wanted to create a `Test` struct:

```
Test get_test()
{
  Test test;
  Foo foo;
  foo.val = 10;
  test.bar = &foo;

  cout << "INIT: " << test.bar->val << endl;

  return test;
}

int main()
{
    Test test = get_test();
    cout << "AFTER: " << test.bar->val << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is the following:

```
INIT: 10
AFTER: 32723
```

I tried to do this differently:

```
Test get_test()
{
  Test test;
  Foo *foo;
  foo->val = 10;
  test.bar = foo;

  cout << "INIT: " << test.bar->val << endl;

  return test;
}
```

But this gave me a `SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)`

From my limited understanding, I believe it is because in `get_test()` `foo` is a temporary variable, so the reference doesn't mean anything. How can I do this properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: That explains really well why it doesn't work, but i'm still confused on how I would do this properly

Comment: @S.M. Correct me if I’m wrong — the relevant concept is not scope, but duration. Scope matters at compile-time; it defines which parts of the code can see which identifiers. Duration matters at runtime; it defines when objects are created and destroyed. Access something after it’s destroyed, it might have the value you expect, or something else; no guarantees either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. In your first example, once `get_test` returns, `foo` does not exist anymore, and accessing the address where it was is undefined behavior. The same happens in your second try, but here the problem is in `get_test` itself. You declare `Foo* foo;`, but never assign it to anything, which means that the variable `foo` is pointing to some random address. Accessing it is undefined behavior. 
Try this as your `get_test`-function:

```
Test get_test()
{
  Test test;
  Foo *foo = new Foo();
  foo->val = 10;
  test.bar = foo;

  cout << "INIT: " << test.bar->val << endl;

  return test;
}
```

Here, we allocate `foo` with `new`, so it is allocated on the heap, and will remain until you call `delete` on it. This means you need to make sure to `delete` it once you are done with it or you will have a memory-leak. In c++14, you could also do it using `std::unique_ptr`:

```
struct Test
{
  std::unique_ptr<Foo> bar;
};
```

```
{
  Test test;
  std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo = std::make_unique<Foo>();
  foo->val = 10;
  test.bar = std::move(foo);

  cout << "INIT: " << test.bar->val << endl;

  return test;
}
```

`std::unique_ptr` will take care of deleting `foo` once it goes out of scope (when `test` is destroyed), and you don't have to worry about memory-leaks (but you cannot copy a `std::unique_ptr`, so you will have to `std::move` it).
`std::unique_ptr` is available since c++11, `std::make_unique` since c++14.
You will also need to `#include <memory>` to be able to use them.
Check out this [link](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/) to learn more about the difference between heap and stack, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010630/move-semantics-with-unique-ptr) to learn more about `std::unique_ptr` and move-semantics.